# Repeatedly reading small file throws OutOfMemory

Tags: c#, file

I have two programs that work together. To coordinate their operations I use a small settings file. This setting file contains two words separated by a ';'. So in the one program I repeatedly read the words in the file using a while loop. By repeatedly I mean once every second. The loop only terminates when the program terminates; when the user turns off the pc.

But with each iteration of the loop the program size in memory increases until the program throws an OutOfMemory exception.  I have tried two different methods of reading the files but both causes the program to 'grow' in memory.

```
FileStream FS = new FileStream("br.stat", FileMode.Open);
StreamReader SR = new StreamReader(FS);
string s = SR.ReadToEnd();
FS.Dispose();
SR.Dispose();
```

and

```
string S = File.ReadAllText("br.stat");
```

Is there a way to read a file repeatedly with out this happening?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure that these lines are causing the exception?

Comment: If you want to communicate between two applications a Socket would probably be more efficient, then you can just send the information when it is available, instead of relying on the file system.

Answer (score 2):

the problem is the design, more so than the implementation. You only need to read from the file once when the app starts and again when the file changes. You can use [FileSystemWatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx) to detect changes to the file and reload the settings.

This uses drastically less resources than reading the file indefinitely.

also, you'll want to take advantage of the `using` keyword to ensure you properly dispose of the file stream and reader. In fact I would simplify and just use `File.ReadAllText(filename)`.

Comment: Pretty much verbatim for what I wrote at the same time.

Comment: Thanks I am now using FileSystemWatcher.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're doing it wrong.  Realistically there is no need to read the file every iteration unless its changed.

Instead it would be better to use a FileSystemWatcher http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.changed(v=vs.85).aspx to read the values and change your control values.

You should also use the following to circumvent your memory leak issues

```
using (var FS = new FileStream("br.stat", FileMode.Open))
{
    using (var SR = new StreamReader(FS))
    {
        var s = SR.ReadToEnd();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recomend you look at using an [using statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx)

> File and Font are examples of managed types that access unmanaged
>   resources (in this case file handles and device contexts). There are
>   many other kinds of unmanaged resources and class library types that
>   encapsulate them. All such types must implement the IDisposable
>   interface.
>
> As a rule, when you use an IDisposable object, you should declare and
>   instantiate it in a using statement. The using statement calls the
>   Dispose method on the object in the correct way, and (when you use it
>   as shown earlier) it also causes the object itself to go out of scope
>   as soon as Dispose is called. Within the using block, the object is
>   read-only and cannot be modified or reassigned.

so something like

```
using (FileStream FS = new FileStream("br.stat", FileMode.Open))
using (StreamReader SR = new StreamReader(FS))
{
    string s = SR.ReadToEnd();
}
```

Comment: This might not solve the issue though if the OP is using the File.ReadAllText method..

Comment: The OP did specify though that it is a small text file.

Comment: I was using a using statement. It still caused the increase in size. I used Dispose() just to see if it will not resolve the problem.